# Passing variable in Python Bottle in Iteration

Tags: python, bottle

I have several lists in this format `mylist1,mylist2,mylist3,mylist4,....`

I am trying to iterate through them in Python Bottle but I cannot find the right way

```
%for i in range(1,21):
{{mylist{{i}}[0]}} or {{mylist~i~[0]}} or {{mylist}}{{i}}[0] or {{mylist+i+[0]}} or {{mylist+i}}[0]
%end
```

But nothing from the above work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the variable value by name from the [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

```
{{locals()['mylist' + str(i)][0]}}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bottle import template
>>> template('{{locals()["list" + str(i)]}}', i=1, list1=[1,2,3,4])
u'[1, 2, 3, 4]'
```

Personally, I don't like the solution. Better construct a `context` dict with `mylist1`, `mylist2` ... `mylistn` as keys and actual lists as values and pass it to the template:

```
>>> template('{{context["list" + str(i)]}}', i=1, context={'list1': [1,2,3,4]})
u'[1, 2, 3, 4]'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great! Thank you. This works but I will try to change it to dict